# How to read from a file through a Static Link library? in visual studio

Tags: c++, file, dll

I am relatively new to programming and I want to know this. I have tried all the ways possible but I am stuck at this point.

Please Help me if possible.

Below is the my SLL to get in order to access the contents in the file and store it in an array:

```
        #pragma once
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

namespace std {

    class SLL
    {

    private:
        ifstream inputFile();

    public:
        //this is where the functions go
        int LoadMeasurements(wchar_t* inputFile, int data[], int maxSize) { 
            ifstream inputFile();

            inputFile.open("inputFile.txt");

            inputFile.close();
        }
    };
}
```

Thank You in Advance

Comment: Could you clarify your exact issue and provide a [mcve]?

Comment: Its depends. what do you want to read?

Comment: Now I see code that opens the file and then closer. You do need code that actually reads the file. Futhermore `data` won't output anything as I explained in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

To load data into array use `std::vector<int>` to instantiate the variable and `std::vector<int>&` to let the function edit it. `int data[]` accepts copy of the input variable and not the variable itself - so editing it is pointless.

```
void fun(int a[])
{
a[0]=1;
a[1]=2;
}

int main()
{
int a[2] = {5,7};
fun(a);
cout<<a[0] << a[1];
return 0;
}
```

This code prints `57` as `fun` changes nothing. While the following code will print `12`:

```
void fun(vector<int>& a)
{
a[0]=1;
a[1]=2;
}

int main()
{
vector<int> a = {5,7};
fun(a);
cout<<a[0] << a[1];
return 0;
}
```

Adding & to `fun`'s input causes it get the variable itself and not a copy of it. While vector allows one to change the size of the container dynamically which is extremely useful in general.